# Using both timeout and semaphore for Thread blocking

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, semaphore

I have a method to run that makes connection to server, and when server fails, would wait until it receives a message that server is up again. However, this entire method should have a timeout, and if it is over the time, method should interrupt and return error log instead.

```
private Semaphore sem = new Semaphore(0);
private TimeUnit unit = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS;

public String some_method(Object params, long timeout, TimeUnit unit) {
    long time = 0;
    while(time < timeout) { // not sure about timeout method
        try {
            //some task that is prone to ServerConnectException
            return; // returns value and exits 
        } catch(ServerConnectException ex) {
            sem.acquire();
        } catch(InterruptedException uhoh) {
            System.out.println("uhoh, thread interrupted");
        }
        // increment time somehow
    }
    sem.release();
    return null; // a message of task incompletion
}
```

- I was thinking about running a thread containing semaphore that blocks thread if there's a server failure problem, but I cannot seem to organize thread such that it will contain the semaphore but be contained by method itself.

QUESTION:
- However, the method is already in a gigantic class and making separate Thread for just that method will mess up entire call hierarchy as well as whole API, so I don't want to do that. I need some process that runs along with the some_method and places lock and release on its processes as needed, with timeout. What should I be thinking? Some other concurrency wrapper like executor?

Thanks!

Comment: I guess you forgot the question

Comment: fixed, danke for pointing out

Comment: Creating a thread instance to invoke a method should have no impact on the design of the method itself, so shouldn't really impact your API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Semaphore doesn't seem to be the right concurrency primitive to use here, as you don't really need a utility for locking, but rather a utility to help you coordinate inter-thread communication.

If you need to communicate a stream of values, you would typically use a blocking queue, but if you need to communicate a single value, a CountDownLatch and a variable do the trick.  For example (untested):

```
  public String requestWithRetry(final Object params, long timeout, TimeUnit unit) throws InterruptedException {
    String[] result = new String[1];
    CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
        while (true) {
          try {
            result[0] = request(params);
            latch.countDown();
            return;
          }
          catch(OtherException oe) {
            // ignore and retry
          }
          catch(InterruptedException ie) {
            // task was cancelled; terminate thread
            return;
          }
        }
      }
    });
    t.start();
    try {
      if (!latch.await(timeout, unit)) {
        t.interrupt(); // cancel the background task if timed out
      }
      // note that this returns null if timed out
      return result[0];
    }
    catch(InterruptedException ie) {
      t.interrupt(); // cancel the background task
      throw ie;
    }
  }

  private String request(Object params) throws OtherException, InterruptedException {
    // should handle interruption to cancel this operation
    return null;
  }
```